# SonarQube 5.6 restore quality profile

Tags: curl, sonarqube

I am trying to restore a quality profile on a fresh installation of SonarQube v.5.6.4 over Web API using curl.

In c:\temp I have an exported "Sonar way" profile from running Sonar and I have renamed it to test.xml (inside, the name was also changed to test so that both profiles are "different").

From the c:\temp location, I used the following curl command:

```
curl -v -X POST -u admin:admin --header "Content-Type: application/xml"
     "http://localhost:9000/api/qualityprofiles/restore" -d backup=test.xml
```

The response was:

```
500 Internal Server Error If you are the administrator of this website, 
then please read this web application's log file to find out what went wrong.
```

No matter how I changed the curl-command (with different content-types, with -F paramter, with @ before file name), I could not manage to fix this problem.

Moreover, I checked Sonar logs which look like this:

```
2017.01.30 14:13:14 ERROR web[rails] /!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Mon Jan 30 14:13:14 +0100 2017
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
    C:/bin/sonarqube-5.6.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/xml_mini/rexml.rb:29:in `merge_element!'
    C:/bin/sonarqube-5.6.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/xml_mini/rexml.rb:18:in `parse'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
    C:1:in `parse'
    C:/bin/sonarqube-5.6.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions.rb:171:in `from_xml'
    C:/bin/sonarqube-5.6.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:34:in `parse_formatted_parameters'
    C:/bin/sonarqube-5.6.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:11:in `call'
    file:/C:/bin/sonarqube-5.6.4/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in `context'
    C:/bin/sonarqube-5.6.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:58:in `call'
    C:/bin/sonarqube-5.6.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
    C:/bin/sonarqube-5.6.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
    file:/C:/bin/sonarqube-5.6.4/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in `serve_rails'
    file:/C:/bin/sonarqube-5.6.4/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in `call'
    file:/C:/bin/sonarqube-5.6.4/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in `call'
```

Is there something wrong with version 5.6.4?

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to my problem was this command:

```
curl -v POST -u admin:admin "http://localhost:9000/api/qualityprofiles/restore"  
--form backup=@test.xml
```

It looks like I didn't try this combination before.

The response was 200 OK:

```
 HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
 Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=A20898D27A0D843EEC6ED9791CABEB49; Path=/; HttpOnly
 X-Runtime: 265
 ETag: "7cce49c3a8a16a16c8c48cc4942df042"
 Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
 X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
 X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
 Content-Length: 166
 Date: Mon, 30 Jan 2017 14:19:51 GMT
```

Comment: It appears that the "POST" option is unnecessary.  The --form option will cause curl to use POST.

Comment: For security purposes, the authentication (-u admin:admin) should be provided in ~/.curlrc to prevent passwords from showing up in command history.  Or, remove the password and let curl prompt for the password as "-u admin:"

Comment: I just noticed I need the `@` in order for my curl to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have all your xml backup files in a single directory, you can restore all of them using only one command in this way : 
C:>for /R . %1 IN (*.xml) DO curl.exe -v -X POST -u admin:admin_password
"http://your_server:9000/sonar/api/qualityprofiles/restore" --form backup=@%1

Cheers

Massimo