# Restore built-in profiles menu not exist in sonarqube 6.7

Tags: sonarqube

I want to use the Quality Profile from SonarQube 5.6 which is built-in profiles. I only can backup the profiles because it's in my company Sonar. I want to use local SonarQube and using version 6.7, but I can't restore the profile as Restore Built-in Profile menu doesn't exist. Is there any way to restore the Built-in Profiles?

Comment: Maybe this menu feature was introduced in 6.x and not available in 5.x? But have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936962/sonarqube-5-6-restore-quality-profile) SO question.

Comment: No. I believe this feature is available in 5. But not in 6. Btw I found the way. I  modify the xml and change the name of profile to other than Sonar Way. Restore it and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Starting [SonarQube 6.5](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-9305), it's no more needed to restore built-in quality profile, because they have become ready-only and are updated automatically.

Comment: Yeah. But for people whant to restore built-in quality profile because they don't have access to duplicate built-in profile with other name, this will hard. But I can restore the backup of built-in quality profile by editing the name of quality profile on xml to other than built-in name.